# Working with Zabbix API from Delphi

Tags: api, delphi, zabbix

can someone provide an example how to work with Zabbix API from Delphi?
Which Delphi component to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the whole Zabbix API is just a JSON-RPC API, accessible via POST calls on one single URL. Further details about API can be found here: 
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api

As can be seen, the only thing you have to do is to make a POST to:

```
http://company.com/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-rpc

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"apiinfo.version","id":1,"auth":null,"params":{}}
```

Now, it does not matter whether you use delphi or not, you only need a component that can build a HTTP request and parse HTTP respone. I found this question, that may be helpful for you, since it seems to handle HTTP POSTs in Delphi.

[What’s the simplest way to call Http POST url using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301991/what-s-the-simplest-way-to-call-http-post-url-using-delphi)

At this time, i don't know any existing Delphi library that would do the magic for you.