# Send and receive XML via POST on Delphi

Tags: xml, api, delphi, post, https

I've seen some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301991/what-s-the-simplest-way-to-call-http-post-url-using-delphi) and there on how to POST data to a server using Indy, but my question is how can I view the answer the server provides?

Here is what I have, from the user [Bruce McGee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19183), and modified myself a bit:

```
function ExecuteAPI: string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=StoreName value="Hálitopuro Produtos">');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=StoreID value="123456"> ');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=Username value="Admin"> ');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=password name=Password value="Password123">');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=method value="ReportView">');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=ObjectID value="425">');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=Par1 value="Category name">');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=Par2 value="Ref/Name/Descr"> ');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=Par3 value="false"> ');
  lParamList.Add('<input type=text name=Par4 value="false"> ');

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

  try
    Result := lHTTP.Post('https://www.rumo.com.br/sistema/adm/APILogon.asp', lParamList);
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The API states that the server also returns a XML, regardless on what the request or result is, but how can I view it? For example, by filling a TMemo?

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to `Memo1.Lines.Text := ...`?

Comment: I think the code in question does not work, as he is using https

Comment: Yeah, If he wanted it to work, he'd have to do some set up for SSL.

Comment: I am still learning to code in Pascal, so a question like that may seem dumb for veteran coders!! I am aware that I have to link the InHTTP to an SSL handler, but let's face one problem at a time!

Comment: @whosrdaddy: actually, it can work as shown, if he is using an up-to-date version of Indy: [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx)

Comment: Memo1.Lines.Text works just fine in this case as Memo1.Text. Thanks!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using DX, so you're right. It works without the SSL components!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I view it, for example, by filling a TMemo?

To view text in a memo control, assign to the `Text` property:

```
Memo1.Text := ExecuteAPI;
```

Answer (score 7):

> I've seen some examples here and there on how to POST data to a server using Indy

You are not populating the `TStringList` correctly.  DO NOT store the actual HTML tags in it, just their `name=value` pairs by themselves, eg:

```pascal
lParamList.Add('StoreName=Hálitopuro Produtos');
lParamList.Add('StoreID=123456');
lParamList.Add('Username=Admin');
lParamList.Add('Password=Password123');
lParamList.Add('method=ReportView');
lParamList.Add('ObjectID=425');
lParamList.Add('Par1=Category name');
lParamList.Add('Par2=Ref/Name/Descr');
lParamList.Add('Par3=false');
lParamList.Add('Par4=false');
```

> how can I view the answer the server provides?

`TIdHTTP.Post()` returns the server's response to you.  There are two overloaded versions of `Post()` for this purpose - one that returns the response as a `String`, and one that fills a `TStream` with the raw response bytes.  You are calling the first one, so just use the `String` however you want, eg:

```pascal
var
  XML: string;
begin
  XML := ExecuteAPI;
  // use XML as needed, for example:
  // Memo1.Text := XML;
end;
```

However, that being said...

> The API states that the server also returns a XML, regardless on what the request or result is

XML is not textual data, it is binary data with textual elements in it.  Treating the XML as binary is important for proper charset handling for non-ASCII characters.  You *should* use the `TStream` version of `Post()` and then load the raw data to an actual XML parser for further processing (as I'm sure you will eventually want to actually do something based on the content of the response, not just look at it), eg:

```pascal
procedure ExecuteAPI(Response: TStream);
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lParamList.Add('StoreName=Hálitopuro Produtos');
    lParamList.Add('StoreID=123456');
    lParamList.Add('Username=...');
    lParamList.Add('Password=...');
    lParamList.Add('method=ReportView');
    lParamList.Add('ObjectID=425');
    lParamList.Add('Par1=Category name');
    lParamList.Add('Par2=Ref/Name/Descr');
    lParamList.Add('Par3=false');
    lParamList.Add('Par4=false');

    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      lHTTP.Post('https://www.rumo.com.br/sistema/adm/APILogon.asp', lParamList, Response);
    finally
      lHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  XML: TMemoryStream;
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XML := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ExecuteAPI(XML);
    XML.Position := 0;
    {Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(XML);
    XML.Position := 0;}
    Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    Doc.LoadFromStream(XML);
  finally
    XML.Free;
  end;
  // use Doc as needed...
end;
```

If you let `TIdHTTP.Post()` return the XML as a `String`, `TIdHTTP` will try to figure out the XML's charset by analyzing the HTTP `Content-Type` header, and potentially also the XML's own prolog declaration, and then decode the raw data to Unicode based on that charset, and then re-encode the Unicode data to a `String` (which will be either Ansi or Unicode depending on your version of Delphi).  That first step is error-prone and could cause data loss, for instance if the HTTP server is misconfigured.  It is better to have `TIdHTTP.Post()` return the raw XML data and let an XML parser handle the charset decoding.  That is part of its job, afterall.

Comment: While David posted the correct answer to this simple question, IMHO this answer should be the most upvoted one :)

Comment: I appreciate the HTML tags tip, and it is actually how we should not do it. But does the server interprets the request as in XML format? The rest of your post will be useful in the next steps of developing my application, I really thank you for your time.

Comment: The *request* is not in any XML format, no. It is submitted in `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` format (since you are simulating a submission of an HTML webform).  If you want to post an actual XML document, post the XML data using a `TStream`-derived object instead of a `TStringList`, the stream data will be posted as-is.

Comment: It was a misunderstood from my part... now, everything works and I can view the response in the Memo. Of course this is for "debugging purposes" and, as you suggested, my application will be picking parts of the XML and throwing them into EditBoxes for further processing.