# idHttp post ListBox or StringList content in json

Tags: json, delphi, indy, http-request

How can I post the content of a `TStringList` or `TListBox` in `JSON` format using `TIdHTTP`?

*Note : I need to post them in one request !*

The content of the list box looks like this :

```
window
door
box
pin
book
lamp
tree
house
roof
..
..
.
```

Comment: do you know how to format your text in JSON?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301991/what-s-the-simplest-way-to-call-http-post-url-using-delphi

Indy post example

Comment: https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject a Delphi Cross Platform Rapid JSON library. Easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Create the JSON data however you want (use [Delphi's own JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON), or a 3rd party JSON library, or just write your own JSON code).  Then store the JSON data in a `TStream`, such as `TStringStream` or `TMemoryStream`, and then pass that stream to `TIdHTTP.Post()`.