# How do I list Pastebin pastes created by a user in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pastebin

I am a beginner in Delphi (I use Delphi 2010 because of school) and I am trying to get an output textfile with a list of pastes that a pastebin user has created, but I am not exactly sure how to do it. On Pastebin.com ([PastebinAPI](https://pastebin.com/api)), they explain how the API works, but I can't get it working on Delphi.

Here is what I have coded so far (I blurred out my details):

```
procedure TfrmLogin.imgLoginButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sSource, sAPI_Dev_Key, sAPI_User_Key, sAPI_Results_Limit, sAPI_Option,
    sListPasteLink: String;
begin

  sSource := 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php/';
  sAPI_Dev_Key := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/';
  sAPI_User_Key := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/';
  sAPI_Results_Limit := '1000/';
  sAPI_Option := 'list';

  sListPasteLink := sSource + sAPI_Dev_Key + sAPI_User_Key +
    sAPI_Results_Limit + sAPI_Option;
end;
```

I am not sure what to do after this, how do I POST this generated link in Delphi to get the list of pastes created?

I tried copying the generated link and pasting it in my web browser, but Pastebin says *This page has been removed!*

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301991/what-s-the-simplest-way-to-call-http-post-url-using-delphi) for a way to do it.

Comment: @Olivier I tried it, but I get this error: IOHandler value is not valid

Comment: @Olivier Could it be that IDHttp does not accept HTTPS links?

Comment: There is a special handling for HTTPS indeed. See my answer.

Comment: Also note that pastebin.com accepts plain HTTP connections. Making SSL work with your old Delphi version might be tricky anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Drop a `TButton`, a `TMemo`, a `TIdHTTP` and a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` on a form. You will also need to copy libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into your application directory (they are provided somehere in the directory where Delphi was installed).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Params: TStringList;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  Params.Add('api_dev_key=*****');
  Params.Add('api_user_key=*****');
  Params.Add('api_option=list');
  try
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried this code in Delphi 2010, unfortunately the SSL version is not compatible, I then decided to downloaded the latest version of Delphi, and your piece of code works perfectly on it. Thank you so much for your help, I spent hours trying to figure this out. Much appreciated Mr. Olivier.