# Returning an XML document from a function

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe5

Im trying to load a remotely hosted XML file using Delphi. I am assuming that I can load it from a Stream. I have a FetchRemote class that fetches the URL stream:

```
function TFetchRemote.StreamFromUrl(filename : String) : TMemoryStream;
var
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
  http : TIdHttp;
begin
  http := TIdHttp.Create();
  memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  http.Get(url + filename, memStream);
  Result := memStream;
end;
```

I am trying to use the returned memory stream to load the remote XML:

```
function TFetchRemoteXML.XMLFromUrl(filename : string) : TXMLDocument;
var
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  memStream := fetchRemote.StreamFromURL(filename);
  try
    memStream.Position := 0;
    Result := TXMLDocument.LoadFromStream(memStream);
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The error that I am getting when I try compiling is: (On the Result return line)

> [dcc32 Error] FetchRemoteXML.pas(31): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor

I have a similar class/method to fetch a remote Bitmap and it works fine. I just can't see what I am doing wrong to fetch the XML. I have tried following some examples in the Delphi help, and tried getting some hints from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087458/load-remote-xml-file) but no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to Delphi (coming from a Ruby background). I am using RAD Studio XE 5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code indicates you might not be aware of object lifetime management rules in Delphi. You might want to take a bit of time and learn that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LoadFromStream` method is an instance method. Which means that you have to instantiate an instance of `TXMLDocument` and call `LoadFromStream` on that.

```
Result := TXMLDocument.Create(Owner);
Result.LoadFromStream(...);
```

You'll need to supply an owner for the object as described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.Create) for the constructor.

Or pass `nil` to the constructor and switch to `IXMLDocument` instead of `TXMLDocument`.

```
function TFetchRemoteXML.XMLFromUrl(filename : string) : IXMLDocument;
var
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  memStream := fetchRemote.StreamFromURL(filename);
  try
    Result := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    Result.LoadFromStream(memStream);
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've tried calling `xml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    Result := xml.LoadFromStream(memStream);` but it returns a different error message: [dcc32 Error] FetchRemoteXML.pas(33): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TXMLDocument' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Comment: That won't work. Compiler explains why not. Do what I say in the answer.