# Firemonkey Delphi TWebBrowser Get Text / HTML

Tags: delphi, text, get, firemonkey, twebbrowser

How can i get text / html from a webpage on Firemonkey platform (Android/iOS).
TWebBrowser Doesn't have anything for this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to call Http GET url using Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301546/whats-the-simplest-way-to-call-http-get-url-using-delphi). Use the Indy example (`TIdHTTP`), not WinINet.

Comment: No it is different. after user change value of inputs of html want to getText of TWebBrowser!

Answer (score 3):

With some test, I combine JAVAScript and Delphi code, there is a workground, please refer to my article: http://firemonkeylessons.blogspot.tw/2015/01/get-htmljson-from-twebbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I use to get html text

```
          function GetURL(const AURL: string): string;
          var
            HttpClient: THttpClient;
            HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
            begin
              HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
              try
                HttpResponse := HttpClient.Get(AURL);
                // memo1.Text:=HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
                Result := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
                finally
                HttpClient.Free;
              end;
            end;
```